# Weird filter results in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, filter

I have some weird filter results with Inkscape. I am using Windows 10 and Inkscape Version 0.92.
When I apply `Filter > Bevel > Combined Lightening` filter the following result is being rendered:

[image]

First I thought it is just a preview to save render performance but as I exported the graphic as .png it still looked the same. What is happing here? In all the "Bevel" tutorial videos it looks all great.

Comment: Related: [Inkscape filters are not rendering correctly](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136759/inkscape-filters-are-not-rendering-correctly)

Comment: What is your zoom level? And do you have "Best Quality (Slowest)" set in your Preferences for Rendering?  See the other [related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136759/inkscape-filters-are-not-rendering-correctly) for more details.

Comment: Rendering setting is "max". However I am on Zoom 278%. That is because the image is 2.75 x 3.750 inch. Otherwise I could not see anything if I would not zoom in. I understand the issue now but I wonder about the following: I export the image as PNG with Width: 1650 Height: 2250 (600dpi). I would've expected that at least the resulting PNG would have a high resoluted bevel at this point.

Comment: No, that won't work.  You should design your artwork larger so that when you output the final PNG it will look good.. This is really only necessary if you are using effects (since these are rendered as rasters). For normal vector work, this is not necessary.

Comment: @BillyKerr So you'd suggest me to not work on the image inch 2.75 x 3.75 but rather working on a way larger scale, export it and then bring it back to 2.75 x 3.75 ?

Comment: Yes that's right.  Set your zoom to 100%, or less. Make the image big enough to view and work on at that scale.